# how to display jquery autocomplete results on other fields?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Appologies, brand new to jquery and autocomplete. Been searching for days but cannot get my head around how to display the result of a query on a website.

Following code is almost identical copy from the jquery autocomplete site http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ , just amended at the end with what my brain refuses to grasp...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jqueryui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags" />
</div>

<p>
The choice you selected is

<script>
???
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any hint/pointer/solution to stop me going round in circles would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2EXbB/ any error in the console? You remove this line _???_  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a "select" event handler to extract the selected value. Like so:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // console.log(ui.item);
        $('p').text('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much! That was the eye-opener i needed :)